# unable to find absolute URL

Tags: java, html, css

I'm writing some code to find absolute URLS of a single webpage:

http://explore.bfi.org.uk/4ce2b69ea7ef3

So far I get all the links of that page and print the absolute urls

Here is part of the code:

```
 Elements hyperLinks = htmlDoc.select("a[href]");

    for(Element link: hyperLinks)
    {
        System.out.println(link.attr("abs:href"));
    }
```

This prints out alot or urls just like the one above. However, it seems to skip a few URLS aswell. The ones it skips are the ones I actually need.

This is one of the a[href] elements its not turning into the absolute URL:

```
<div class="title"><a href="/4ce2b69ea7ef3">Royal Review</a><br /></div>
```

It will print this line if I just print "link" but when I put "abs:href", it will just print blank.

I am new to Java and appreciate any feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use "a[href]", use "a" instead following [this example](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/working-with-urls):

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://jsoup.org").get();

Element link = doc.select("a").first();
String relHref = link.attr("href"); // == "/"
String absHref = link.attr("abs:href"); // "http://jsoup.org/"
```

So in your case:

```
Elements hyperLinks = htmlDoc.select("a");

    for(Element link: hyperLinks)
    {
        System.out.println(link.attr("abs:href"));
    }
```

Comment: Wow thanks this is very useful to me! However i'm getting "/4ce2b699a9880" Could I turn this into absolute Url?

Comment: Ive managed to do it now using the source you gave me! thank you!